# tex2lyx drops underscores and circumflex accents

Tags: lyx

An old tex-file that I need to edit imports rather well in LyX, but all underscores and circumflex accents are simply removed. That is: when LyX is able to detect that math-mode is active, it interprets these accents correctly as subscripts and superscripts, but it just drops them when it thinks it is handling plain text.

Here's a short example:

```
Twee {\trm termen} $a_m$ en $a_n$ $(m>n)$ in een MR liggen $m-n$ 
posities uit elkaar. Hieruit volgt dat
\beq a_m=a_n\cdot r^{m-n}. \eeq
```

The 'a_m' between $-tags is imported correctly. The 'a_m' between \beq and \eeq should be imported literally as 'a_m' for my purposes, but instead is imported as 'am'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: replace the `\beg` and `\eeq` with `\[` and `\]` and the conversion should work.

Comment: cross-post: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=26948